# Adding a field to differentiate parts of tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I have several gigabites of arducopter binary flight logs. Each log is a series of messages.

```
MessageType1: param1, param2, param3
MessageType2: param3, param4, param5, param6
...
```

The logs are self describing in the sense that the first time a message appears in the log it tells what are the names of the params.

```
MessageType1: timestamp, a, b
MessageType1: value 1, value 2, value 3
MessageType2: timestamp, c, d, e
MessageType1: value 4, value 5, value 6
MessageType1: value 7, value 8, value 9
MessageType2: value 10, value 11, value 12, value 13
```

I have written a python script that takes the logs apart and creates tables for each message type in a sqlite database where the message type is the table name and the parameter name is the column name.

Table MessageType1

```
| Flight Index | Timestamp |   a   |    b    |
|--------------|-----------|-------|---------|
| ...          |           |       |         |
| "Flight 1"   |       111 | 14725 | 10656.0 |
| "Flight 1"   |       112 | 57643 | 10674.0 |
| "Flight 1"   |       113 | 57157 | 13674.0 |
| ...          |           |       |         |
| "Flight 2"   |       111 | 56434 | 16543.7 |
| "Flight 2"   |       112 | 56434 | 16543.7 |
```

Table MessageType2

```
| Flight Index | Timestamp |   c   |    d    |   e    |
|--------------|-----------|-------|---------|--------|
| ...          |           |       |         |        |
| "Flight 1"   |       111 | 14725 | 10656.0 | 462642 |
| "Flight 1"   |       112 | 57643 | 10674.0 | 426428 |
| "Flight 1"   |       113 | 57157 | 13674.0 | 642035 |
| ...          |           |       |         |        |
| "Flight 2"   |       111 | 56434 | 16543.7 | 365454 |
| "Flight 2"   |       112 | 56434 | 16543.7 | 754632 |
| ...          |           |       |         |        |
```

For a single log this database is good enough but i would like to add several logs. Meaning messages of several logs of same type go into a single table.

In this case I added a column "Flight Index" which is what I would like to have but:

- Each log processed should have a unique identifier
- The identifier should be minimal in size, as im dealing with tables that have possibly millions of rows.

Im thinking of adding the flight index as an integer and just iterating the number when processing logs and if the database exists taking the last row of a table and using its index + 1. Is this optimal or is there a SQL native way of operating?

Am i doing something wrong in general as I'm not experienced with SQL?

EDIT: added a second table to show that messages dont have the same number of parameters and example messages.

Comment: If I understand correctly your "Flight Index" is equivalent to rowid. If this is true then you don't need to create it and the default one should be used instead. Which has the maximum value 9223372036854775807. I guess it should be enough. For more information http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/
Correct me if I misunderstood something

Comment: Well as i wrote in the table one "Flight Index" can map to something like 20 000 rows. I would like to have something similarly light weight that allows me to differentiate between variable length chunks across several tables. OR i could create a table of flights and treat each rowid as an identifier in all of the message_type tables. Is that what you meant?

Comment: What @MikitaHerasiutsin is suggesting (correct me if I'm wrong, here) is to have a parent table with one record per flight.  That will allow you to store flight-specific information once.  The arducopter logs would then be children to that flight record.

Comment: After reading [database normalization wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) i understood that i was indeed lacking in my understanding of relational databases. My own solution this far is to make 3 tables: Flight, Parameters, Messages where the columns would be Event ID, Flight ID for flight, Event ID, Parameter Name, Parameter Value for parameters and Event ID, Message Name for messages. Can i do better? Seems like this would increase the size of my database.

Comment: Ah, that would mean alot of repetiton of the Parameter Name so this should be in the forth table with its own ID to be referenced but then the names can be repeated so i need to check for that aswell.... Seems i have more to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading about [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) I ended up with the following database.

[image: schema]

This minimizes the number of tables. I could have done 35 tables (one for each message) and right parameters for each column, but that would make the database more fragile in the case where the parameters in a message are changed.

EDIT: replaced the image as datamodler got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with two tables

Table 1

```
Flights 
Flight name, Flight number, date, device, etc. (any other data points make sense)
"Flight 1", 1, 1/1/2018,...
"Flight 2", 2, 1/2/2018,...
```

Table 2

```
Flight_log
Flight_number, timestamp, parameter1, parameter2,
1,111,14725,10656.0
1,112,57643,10674.0 
1,113,57157,13674.0 
...         
2,111,56434,16543.7 
2,112,56434,16543.7
```

Before you load Flight_logs table you should have an entry in Flights table, you can do a "lookup" do get the Flight_number from Flight table